# Installation Zeppelin issue: how to fix the dependencies without Internet?

Tags: software-installation, repository, maven

I am installing Zeppelin in a private network.

So far, four modules need a local repository to be built.

> ```
> zeppelin-beam 
> zeppelin-bigquery 
> zeppelin-postgresql 
> zeppelin-shell
> ```

I got this information from the following logs.

```
    Install beam(org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-beam:0.7.1) to /opt/zeppelin-0.7.1-bin-all/interpreter/beam ...
    org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-beam:0.7.1
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:172)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.installAll(InstallInterpreter.java:122)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:272)
    Install bigquery(org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-bigquery:0.7.1) to /opt/zeppelin-0.7.1-bin-all/interpreter/bigquery .        ..
    org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-bigquery:0.7.1
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:172)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.installAll(InstallInterpreter.java:122)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:272)
org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-postgresql:0.7.        1
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.installAll(InstallInterpreter.java:122)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:272)
org.sonatype.aether.RepositoryException: Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-shell:0.7.1
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.getArtifactsWithDep(DependencyResolver.java:181)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.loadFromMvn(DependencyResolver.java:131)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:79)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:96)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.DependencyResolver.load(DependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.installAll(InstallInterpreter.java:122)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:272)
```

Take

> zeppelin-beam

for example, to compile this module, the dependencies info can be got from this java `pom.xml`

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/61aeeaf10f340879337b6f19c5a9b3aaaa4eca9e/beam/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.spark.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.spark-project.akka</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.spark-project.akka</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.10</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.spark-project.akka</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.spark.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
  <artifactId>zeppelin-scio_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.hadoop.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.thoughtworks.qdox</groupId>
  <artifactId>qdox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-M3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-parent</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.beam.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-core-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.beam.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.beam.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.beam.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
  <version>${beam.beam.version}</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>zeppelin-interpreter</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
  <version>${commons.exec.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> My questions are around the background information:
>   1. What maven repositories contain these dependencies? 
>   2. How many kinds of repositories are there on the website? 
>   3. How many kinds / What origination are maintaining them?